# NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. (even after driver reinstall )

Tags: drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, cuda

i had faced with an issue on nvidia driver for 2080Ti (need to install nvidia driver + CUDA for torch usage).

```
me@server:~$ python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, Aug 20 2019, 17:12:48)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()
False
```

i think that issue is caused by the next problem:

```
me@server:~$ sudo nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver.
Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

of course, i had googled a lot on this issue and tried all found solutions: i had re-install all drivers from scratch, tried different versions of the drivers (385, 410, 415, 430, 435). unfortunately, all these steps didn't help.

i need something fresh solution on it :)

P.S. of course, re-install Ubuntu will work, but right now i have no time to do it because i need to run torch :(

Comment: Disable Secure Boot and try again.

Comment: already did it - doesn't help in my case

Comment: So you need to purge all Nvidia drivers before any further attempts and install only versions that support your card which is the same to as saying only the latest version.

Comment: Yes, i did it before each reinstall